# How to interpolate values using a for loop?

Tags: r

I am trying to interpolate values from a data frame i have imported from excel. In the table are two columns (value 1 and Value 2) that I am trying to interpolate for each unique "Name". The data frame contains 550 rows with 90 unique Names (so each Name has more than one "Value1" value and more than one "Value2" value). There are also a bunch of irrelevant columns in the dataframe which I don't have a use for.

Example of data frame:

```
Name   Value1  Value2  NotImportantvalue1  NotImportantvalue2 
    A       1         1            ABC                ABC
    A       2         1            ABC                ABC
    B       40        40           ABC                ABC 
    C       30        30           ABC                ABC   
    C       1         2            ABC                ABC
    D       2         400          ABC                ABC
    D       3         500          ABC                ABC
    D       40        2            ABC                ABC
```

I've been messing around with for loops that cycles through a dataframe containing the unique values of Names trying to make it go through the Value1/Value2 columns in my.data where the name in the "Name" column matches the name in the unique dataframe, but I'm not getting the results I want.

Where I'm currently at with my code is to try to get Value1 and Value2 when i in the dataframe "Name" matches the value in the column "Name" in my.data and saving as a dataframe with the same name. After that I have to figure out how to interpolate the values in each dataframe.

```
    #Set working directory
    setwd("H:\\R-project")

    #Set file path
    file <- file.path("Data.xlsx")

    #set library
    library(XLConnect)

    #Read data
    my.data <- readWorksheetFromFile(file,sheet=1,startRow=1)

    #Unique Names
    Name <- data.frame(unique(my.data$Names))
    colnames(Name) <- "Name"

for (i in Name$Name) {
  assign(i, data.frame(my.data$Value1[my.data$Name==Name[[i],]], my.data$Value2[my.data$Name==Name[[i],]])

}
```

I'm also not sure if using 90 individual data.frames is the way to go or if i should use something like

```
name_list <- split(my.data, as.factor(my.data$name))
```

and interpolate from the list directly (although i don't know exactly how to do that either, for loops aren't my strong point).

Any guidance or help on how to continue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by `interpolate values`? For your toy example where `Name==A`, what would the output of interpolating of `Value1,Value2` be?

Comment: Well I would be using the approx() function to interpolate new values based on the values i already have.                  Value1 is time (how many days) and Value2 is observed data points. So for the first entry "A" there is one observed data point in 1 day and for the second entry of "A" there is one observed data point in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested

```
name_list <- split(my.data, my.data$name)
```

will give you a `list` of data frames that have been split by `name`

You can operate on that list using something like the following

```
lapply(name_list, function(x) approx(x$Value1, x$Value2))
```

You will need to provide more details on the desired output if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: This works exactly how I want it! Thanks, can't believe it was such an easy solution. Been pulling my hair out trying to make a for loop.

Comment: Hmm, might have been a bit fast in saying it worked. When i checked the solution closer it approxes all values for Value1 and Value2 everytime for Name A,B,C but I want it to only approx the values in the same row as the given name. Any ideas?